# One Virtual Host acting differently than others

Tags: ssl, redirect, apache-2.4, tls

I have three virtual host sites enabled on apache2 all using TLS/SSL certificates.  I want to redirect the non-ssl (http) to the ssl (https).  I am using a redirect in each virtual host.  All three .conf files are exactly the same as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site_folder/
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

...and the ssl section down here which is working fine
```

I realize that I do not need to specify the DocumentRoot if I am using a Redirect in this way.

The problem is that two of the virtual hosts work perfectly and always redirect to https://www.example.com as I desire.  However, one site does not.  It simply redirects to https://example.com (without the www.)

So, I'm totally confused about this.

I have tried enabling and disabling the site (a2ensite, a2dissite), I have tried also to copy the whole file to a new site and create a new one, and restarting apache2 and the whole server.  I am completely confused about this.

Comment: Clearly, your claim that all three .conf files are the same is incorrect, or else there's some other relevant configuration that you haven't shared.  Please provide *all* the relevant configuration information.

Comment: Well, that will reveal my DNS information for the sites I'm working on.

Comment: I've actually taken out the line: "Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/" from all 3 virtual hosts and they still route to the https automatically.  The same one still goes without a www.  Is there another place where this routing could be taking place?

Comment: Yes, it could be happening in all sorts of places.  Only you, as the person who set this up, can know for sure what else could be getting in the way.